# Ruby : How to correctly calculate date difference?

Tags: ruby, debugging, date, date-difference

I began with `(date2 - date1).round`, now this should have work.

**Problem :**

**06 Jan,2013 to 05 Feb,2013  => `30`**

**06 Feb,2013 to 05 Mar,2013  => `27`**

**06 Mar,2013 to 05 Apr,2013  => `30`**

**06 Apr,2013 to 27 Apr,2013  => `21`**

```
(Date.strptime('05 Feb,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Jan,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
(Date.strptime('05 Mar,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Feb,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
(Date.strptime('05 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Mar,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
(Date.strptime('27 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Apr,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
```

Therefore,

```
    Total = 108 days [ 30 + 27 + 30 + 21 ]
```

**But when I try to calculate it in 1 go as :**

```
(Date.strptime('27 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Jan,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
```

This gives :

```
Days = 111 days
```

Now, **108 days != 111 days**

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have an off-by-one error in your first method.  You're not counting the day between the calculations.

Comment: Actually between 6 Jan and 27 Apr there are 111 days.

Comment: I'm not sure, but is Ruby picky about spaces?  You have an extra space between the `,` and the `%Y` formatter on the left side but not on the right.

Comment: Nice catch - although the code actually works. May be they have `strip` logic somewhere in `date` lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing one day between the intervals in your first code.

I increased the end date of first 3 dates, so it matches the start of the next.

```
p (Date.strptime('06 Feb,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Jan,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
p (Date.strptime('06 Mar,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Feb,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
p (Date.strptime('06 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Mar,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
p (Date.strptime('27 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Apr,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
```

Output:

```
31
28
31
21
```

Sum = 111

Answer (score 0):

Thans, @Dogbert. You are right I am missing it by `1`

Although, as suggested I am missing by `1 day` in all calculations.. i.e.

`Neither of 108 or 111 are correct - Instead both are wrong`

Since, its calculating the `difference between` open range `(d1, d2) instead of [d1, d2)`

Therefore, I should add to all of them :

```
1 + (Date.strptime('05 Feb,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Jan,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
1 + (Date.strptime('05 Mar,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Feb,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
1 + (Date.strptime('05 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Mar,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
1 + (Date.strptime('27 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Apr,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
```

Therefore, total = 112 [ This time ]

Similarly, I should `add 1` to to full-range :

```
1 + (Date.strptime('27 Apr,2013', '%d %b, %Y') - Date.strptime('06 Jan,2013', '%d %b,%Y')).round
```

This sums to `1 + 111` = 112 [ Single total ]

Therefore, `112 == 112`